# Getting host out of text full list of urls

Tags: php, regex

I am getting a piece of text containing a few urls. I want to extract a list of hosts present in the urls given in the text. for example:

INPUT:

```
www.jenniferlopezonline.com www.jenniferlopez.com www.twitter.com/jlo www.myspace.com/jenniferlopez www.youtube.com/jenniferlopez
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Array(
[0]=>www.jenniferlopezonline.com
[1]=>www.jenniferlopez.com
[2]=>www.twitter.com
[3]=>www.myspace.com
[4]=>www.youtube.com
);
```

I tried this code:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-z0-9\_\.\-]+)/i',$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output is somewhat like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => www.jenniferlopezonline.com
[1] => www.jenniferlopez.com
[2] => www.twitter.com
[3] => www.myspace.com
[4] => www.youtube.com
)

[1] => Array
(
[0] => www.jenniferlopezonline.com
[1] => www.jenniferlopez.com
[2] => www.twitter.com
[3] => www.myspace.com
[4] => www.youtube.com
)

[2] => Array
(
[0] => .
[1] => .
[2] => .
[3] => .
[4] => .
)
);
```

converting this output in the desired output will cost me some more code which will make the process slow. I will get data in bulk so I cant afford it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the unnecessary parentheses. They are capturing groups which generate the additional arrays in the first place (and the expensive thing in the engine):

```
preg_match_all('/[a-z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-z0-9\_\.\-]+/i',$text,$matches);
```

This will give you the desired array in `$matches[0]` instead of immediately in `$matches`, but it is not possible to change that behavior. Plus, this already saves you the most overhead of the computation. Assigning `$matches[0]` to `$array` is probably comparably negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which will give you an associative array of the components of your URL.

For example:

```
$parts = parse_url('http://twitter.com/jlo');
echo $parts['host'];
```

Will print `twitter.com`.

Make sure your URLs include the `http://` scheme.